# Accessing controller params inside of rails model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have params[:tab] within my activities controller. This is used to switch between different tabs on a view. I want to be able to access this param within my model method self.search_my_work.

Activities controller

```
if params[:tab].blank? || params[:tab] == 'active' || params[:tab] == 'inactive' || params[:tab] == 'overdue'
```

Activities model

```
    if tab == 'overdue'
   do this
    else
      do this        
   end
```

As it stands right now I get a Name error.
I am aware it needs instantiated but I don't know how.

Comment: Pass it from the controller explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly access controller params in your model and should not.

**Solution:**

Pass it as a param to the method

E.g:

```
# controllers/activities_controller.rb

Activity.results_for(params[:tab])
```

And use it

```
# models/acctivity.rb

def self.results_for(status)
  where(status: status)
end
```

Comment: Is there anything else I still need to do? I still get the same name error.

Comment: @SolitaryCoder: then you must have implemented this advice incorrectly.